# SystemJS - Provide JQuery global object

Tags: systemjs, jspm

I have a project which is a mix of new code and old libraries, some of which is based on JQuery and JQuery plugins. I'm facing some issues where some plugins are using the global object ($) to integrate, and other are doing `require("jquery")` or the equivalent. This appears to be fetching two different instances of JQuery.

Because of some existing code, I need the global object to be there. However, to support my newer code I want anything that `require`s or `import`s 'jquery' to be provided the window.jQuery object instead of trying to load an external module.

Can I do this with SystemJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the SystemJS-Adapter-Modules? Create a file jquery.js and reference the globally loaded jQuery function:

```
module.exports = window.jQuery;
```

When you import "jquery" you should get a reference to the already loaded jQuery function.

[SystemJS-Adapter-Modules](https://github.com/systemjs/builder#adapter-modules)

Comment: That's what I ended up going with in the end. I didn't realise there was a term for it, so thanks for that and the link!